# Semantic ui changing the position of fullcalender popover?

Tags: javascript, html, css, fullcalendar, semantic-ui

I'm using the semantic ui and fullcalender cdn in the same file.

According to fullcalender documentation popover position is absolute to the it's current table cell. like this one.

[image]

but in my case fullcalender popover showing in the top left corner of the calender. like this one.

[image]

fullcalender code that I have written.

```
  var events = JSON.parse(document.getElementById('mydata').textContent);

  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');
    var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
      initial view: 'dayGridMonth',
      height: 800,
      dayMaxEventRows: true,
      events: events,
      headerToolbar: {
        start: 'dayGridMonth,dayGridWeek',
        center: 'title',
        end: 'today,prev,next'
      },
      eventContent: function( info ) {
        return {html: info.event.title};
      }
    });
    calendar.render();
  });
```

when i remove the cdn of semantic UI it works fine. basically, fullcalender adds position to the top and left on popover but semantic UI removes those positions that's why it happening. how to fix it?